# The issue of failed development effectiveness in using Taiwind CSS with npm and CDN

Tags: npm, tailwind-css, cdn

I would like to ask about the usage of ring- (no thick border) and !important (to override without using it) in Tailwind CSS.

Although I have installed it via npm, many styles still require CDN to work correctly.

You can try commenting out the CDN to see the difference.

Code link (with some comments ,sorry!!):
https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1WOK5bE-DTMGY4-dDXXGV_GM63RB6xXJv?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

You have no transpiler (e.g. [webpack](https://webpack.js.org/), [babel](https://babeljs.io/)) defined in your package.json file. ES6 imports only work in framework environments like React, NextJS, etc. The code needs to be transpiled into browser-readable JavaScript.

I suggest you check into using such frameworks or learn how to use a transpiler manually.

Comment: But what I meant was that I used CSS and did not use ES6. 
I followed the tutorial article, but did not succeed like the author did. 
Here is the article:
 https://ithelp.ithome.com.tw/questions/10212296

and git
https://github.com/huibizhang/ithelp-ironman2021-day16-practice-project/tree/day16-done